# Python Django Celery is taking too much memory

Tags: django, python-2.7, celery, django-celery, nohup

I am running a celery server which have 5,6 task to run periodically. Celery is taking too much memory after 5,6 days of continuous execution.

Celery documentation is very confusing. I am using following settings.

```
# celeryconfig.py
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'xxx.settings'
# default RabbitMQ broker
BROKER_URL = "amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//"

from celery.schedules import crontab
# default RabbitMQ backend
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = None

#4 CONCURRENT proccesess are running.
CELERYD_CONCURRENCY = 4

# specify location of log files
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/celery.log"

CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True

CELERY_IMPORTS = (
    'xxx.celerydir.cron_tasks.deprov_cron_script',

                )

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'deprov_cron_script': {
    'task': 'xxx.celerydir.cron_tasks.deprov_cron_script.check_deprovision_vms',
    'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=17),
    'args': ''
    }
}
```

I am running celery service using nohup command(this will run this in background).

```
 nohup celery beat -A xxx.celerydir &
```

Comment: How much is too much? it's normal for each Celery worker to take around ~150mb in RAM space

Comment: it was taking 80% for 2GB RAM(after 5,6 days).

Comment: It may be a memory leak in your Python/Django program. Does your program use any large lists or dictionaries? Is it Python-only, or does it have any modules written in C?

Comment: Code is pure python but using large list like 5000 objects. Nothing else is running on this server except celery. I think I am missing something in configuration.

Comment: OUTPUT of command to check resource usage of a process.

# top -H -p 19531


19531 root      20   0  857m 405m 8068 S  0.0 21.6   8:19.07 [celery beat] b

19538 root      20   0  857m 405m 8068 S  0.0 21.6   0:00.28 /usr/bin/python

Comment: Showing 21.6% memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

After going through documentation. I came to know that **DEBUG** was **True** in settings.

Just change value of DEBUG in settings.

REF:https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2927